# Dynamic Text Template Transformation at Run-Time

Tags: c#, t4

I want to transform text template contents to the corresponding cs file at run-time, then compile and run it dynamicly in my C# application.
How can I transform the text template to a cs file using the TextTransform Utility?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx

Comment: OK. But I want generate the Foo.tt and the Foo.cs at run-time while according to this link, these files must be made at design-time.

Comment: you can create Foo.tt at design time, and run TransformText() method in runtime

Comment: The article relies on the .cs file being generated and compiled into the assembly at design time.  How can you take a raw-text .tt file at runtime and transform it?